# Router angular : the guard is resolved before the resolve

Tags: angular

I got a problem with Angular 5 router. My ParamsResolve is a service which retrieve all the application's settings, so I have to load it first. 
In order to do that, I set the call in a resolve service `params: ParamsResolve,`
I have a guard (`RightRouteGuard`) in the feature module `StatsModule` that need Params to be resolved first, but when I navigate to the stats path, the guard is resolved before the Params...

My app routing :

```
const routes: Routes = [
{
path: '',
resolve: {
  params: ParamsResolve,
},
canActivate: [LoginRouteGuard],
children: [
  {
    path: 'stats',
    loadChildren: 'app/stats/stats.module#StatsModule',
  }
]
},
```

Feature module routing :

```
{
path: '',
canActivate: [RightRouteGuard], 
data: { 
  expectedRight: [6, 69]
},
component: ConvertComponent
```

}

What I missed ? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously **canActivate** will be resolved first since it's intended to do so - canActivate makes sure that whether you're permitted to use the route.

**resolve** is to fetch the data before navigating to the route.

Thanks